# Windows Server 2008 - is there some kind of 'Developer Edition'?

Tags: licensing, windows-server-2008

just wondering: is there some kind of 'Express' edition of Windows Server 2008 that developers can use to build and test sites locally? I want to test my sites in IIS7 (and learn my way around the OS), but I can't justify buying a full license just for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

There is a MSDNAA (MSDN Academic Alliance) edition for educational institutions. Students get it for free but it doesn't allow production use.

There is also a evaluation edition (downloadable directly from the MS site), it will run for 240 days (8 months).

Ah no, I take that back, 240 days was for the original release. R2 already has the evaluation limited to 180 days. Seems this option has been massively abused.

Comment: Ok thanks - 180 days should at least be enough time to develop and test my personal web site.

Comment: Well, it turns out that you can no longer get a 32 bit version of the trial, which rules me out unless I buy a new machine. Thanks, Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check out Microsoft's new [WebsiteSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/), I think that will help you out.

It provides real editions of various Microsoft software to developers just getting started.

Comment: That looks great, the only problem is that from what I can gather it's only for companies (not private individuals such as myself).